# Rocket.chat custom login using AWS cognito

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, rocket.chat

Issue:
I'm encountering difficulties integrating custom login using AWS Cognito into Rocket.Chat. Although the login form successfully communicates with AWS Cognito and returns a positive response, Rocket.Chat's authentication flow doesn't recognize it.

Context:
I've utilized the AWS-identity-js package for this integration, ensuring proper communication with AWS Cognito. However, I need assistance understanding Rocket.Chat's authentication flow and making the necessary customizations to align it with AWS Cognito.

Questions:

Can someone provide insights into Rocket.Chat's authentication flow to help troubleshoot the integration with AWS Cognito?

What specific customizations are required within Rocket.Chat to ensure seamless integration with AWS Cognito? Are there any endpoint configurations or adjustments needed?

Additionally, I aim to incorporate identity provider (IDP) buttons available in my AWS Cognito user pool into Rocket.Chat's login interface. How can I achieve this while maintaining the integration with AWS Cognito?

custom login using AWS cognito